# ("remotely") Managing filters with Horde 3.3.13

Tags: email, email-server, filter, thunderbird, horde

I'm using [Horde](https://www.horde.org/) 3.3.13 (which is [an old version](https://www.horde.org/download/horde) I know) and uses the [filters](https://kb.iweb.com/hc/en-us/articles/230264548-How-to-setup-email-filters-in-Horde) all the time.

I know that [thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird), for instance, [also support filters](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Read-send-and-organize-emails/Organize-Your-Messages-by-Using-Filters/ta-p/16488).

Is there a way to synchronize the filters on Horde with filters that I could edit locally, on my machine, using Thunderbird? I'd love to be able to edit those filters remotely, is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

Horde's filtering depends on `dovecot` which plugin `pidgeonhole` implements `sieve` filtering language. Dovecot launch the service `managesieve` that listen on the port 4190 (port 2000 is deprecated).

So if your MUA support managesieve protocol (TB is ok) you can access your server-side filtering rules. Server-side is preferrable against local ones because you have to maintain the single set of rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, if I understand correctly, you're suggesting to install [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) on the server and to use the [pigeonhole](https://pigeonhole.dovecot.org/download.html) plugin to remotely manage the filters using Thunderbird. That's good to know, but I don't have access to the server: Horde is installed and I can't modify that. Maybe I shouldn't have asked this question on Serverfault, or maybe I should have been more clear in my question?

Comment: If you already have server-side sieve functionality then it is very probable you already have dovecot's pidgeonhole or something compatible installed. Try to connect to the server via port 4190 or 2000 (for early versions) from the TB.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But I have no idea how to do that! I'll try to google around.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the way, I award you the bounty, but won't mark your answer as accepted, for it didn't really addressed my problem.